# Problema de sql en php

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Tengo un problema en la tendencia de `SQL` en `PHP`

```
$where = '';
$sTable = "clientes";
$type = 'client(1);';
$usid = $_COOKIE['c_user'];
$where = "";;
if($_GET['q']!= "" ){
  $where.= " WHERE  fullname like '%$q%' AND user_id=1 ";
}
$where.="order by fullname desc";
$query_Dataclient = ("SELECT * FROM  $sTable $where LIMIT $offset,$maximo_pagina");
$Dataclient = mysql_query($query_Dataclient, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Dataclient = mysql_fetch_assoc($Dataclient);
$totalRows_Dataclient = mysql_num_rows($Dataclient);
```

Error que sale: 
En el que dice `if($_GET['q'])!='')` ese si funciona bien el otro nose no funciono ni con `AND` ni `WHERE`
mensaje error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND user_id=1 LIMIT 0,7' at line 1

Comment: No se lee el mensaje de error, parece que se ha cortado. Pone "Error que sale:" y nada más. Por otro lado, deberías evitar el uso de las funciones `mysql_*" y pasar a `mysqli` o `PDO`. Y también deberías cambiar el `if($_GET['q']!= "" )` por `isset()` o `empty()` si quieres comprobar existencia y que sea diferente de una cadena vacía.

Comment: ¿has probado que la consulta funciona bien en phpmyadmin o algún cliente tipo workbench?

Comment: Usa mysqli en vez de mysqll. Es igual pero mas moderno.
Por ejemplo, mysql_fetch_assoc seria mysqli_fetch_assoc
Quita los parentesis de la consulta que están por fuera de las comillas dobles.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND user_id=1 LIMIT 0,7' at line 1

Comment: Tu segundo `$where = "";;` tiene un punta coma demás, no sé si será la causa de tu error, pero prueba a ver si te sigue lanzando algún error.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me sucedió una vez que al poner en el `string` una variable no me la reconocía, prueba lo siguiente:

```
$where = '';
$sTable = "clientes";
$type = 'client(1);';
$usid = $_COOKIE['c_user'];
$where = "";;
if($_GET['q']!= "" ){
$where.= " WHERE  fullname like '%".$_GET['q']."%' AND user_id=1 ";
}
$where.="order by fullname desc";
$query_Dataclient = ("SELECT * FROM  $sTable $where LIMIT $offset,$maximo_pagina");
$Dataclient = mysql_query($query_Dataclient, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Dataclient = mysql_fetch_assoc($Dataclient);
$totalRows_Dataclient = mysql_num_rows($Dataclient);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sTable = "clientes";
$type = 'client(1);';
$usid = $_COOKIE['c_user'];
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"]);
$where = "";
if(isset($q)){
  $where= " WHERE  fullname like '%$q%' AND user_id=1 ";
}
$where.="order by fullname desc";
$query_Dataclient = ("SELECT * FROM  $sTable $where LIMIT $offset,$maximo_pagina");
$Dataclient = mysql_query($query_Dataclient, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Dataclient = mysql_fetch_assoc($Dataclient);
$totalRows_Dataclient = mysql_num_rows($Dataclient);
```

Cuando usas `.=` significa que le añades valores a la variable. En la primer variable `$where` no tenias ningun valor, que hasta ahí esta bien, pero dentro de la declaracion `if` seguias añadiendo valores a la variable.
Otra cosa es que no tenias ningun valor a la variable `$q`.Espero funcione!. Saludos